# <div> won't drag

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically positioning images onscreen. Each image has a +/- button to modify its size (displays on top of img on div mouseover). Each image must be dragabble.

My javascript works fine if I set the img as `class="drag"` but it does not work for the div - obviously I want the buttons to drag too. Here is the html fragment (which resides inside a `div` with `position:relative`):

```
<div class="drag" onmouseover="showDIVChild(this)" onmouseout="hideDIVChild(this)">
  <img id="my_img_1" style="width:100; height:100;" src="http://www.whatever.com/images/whatever.jpg"/>
  <button id="but_A_1" style="display:none; width:10;height:15; position:absolute; left:5px; top:5px;" onClick="upSizeIMG('my_img_1')">+</button>
  <button id="but_B_1" style="display:none; width:10;height:15; position:absolute; left:20px; top:5px;" onClick="downSizeIMG('my_img_1')">-</button>
</div>
```

I am using Javascript as provided by [Luke Breuer](http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx). NB The 'drag' class has `position:absolute` set in CSS.

Why won't the `div` drag? (All the other functionality is working)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you create a jsfiddle example to reproduce what you are seeing? That will help us debug your issue.

Comment: I don't see a script to download there. Could you please point to it, or show us the code that makes `.drag` elements draggable?

Comment: click on the 'Luke Breur' link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the answer. I adjusted Luke's code in the onMOuseDown function as follows. NB I'm, not saying there was anything wrong with his code - this is just what I need when a div has an img in it; as the img gets the 'drag' event instead of the div.

Before:

```
var target = e.target != null ? e.target : e.srcElement;
```

After:

```
var target = e.target != null ? e.target.parentNode : e.srcElement.parentNode;
```